# How to put a php variable into an HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have code that queries an SQL database and displays all of the users in a table, that all works fine, from there you are able to click any user and it displays another table that contains all of their information, that also works fine.

The problem I am running into here is on the page that displays the table of the selected users information. On that page I have a button that allows the user information to be edited and update the DB.

Here is the code for the button:

```
 print "<form method='post' action='adminedituser.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' />   
<input type='submit' value='Click here to edit this user' />
</form>";
```

When I click this it takes me to a page with an input box that needs to display the current username and allow the user to put in a new value and submit.

I'm trying to call a php variable inside of the HTML form I have:

```
<?php

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id"); 
//Make db connection
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());

//Step 2: select your db to use
mysql_select_db("final",$conn);

//Step 3: Write the sql that we want to run against the database
$result = mysql_query("select id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, favchar, bio from user where id=$id");

$username = $result["username"];

?>


<form method='post' id='myForm' name='input' action='adduser.php'>
Username: <input type='text' value="<?php echo ($username); ?>" id='uName' name='uName'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

The problem is that the variable $username is not being displayed as the text box value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the following to the end of your mysql_query: or die(mysql_error()). Tell us what is returned, if anything.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if I don't say it someone else is: Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. You can still use the procedural style, if you want (although I can say firsthand it is VERY easy to learn the object style), you just need to do a quick brush up on `mysqli`. `Mysql` is deprecated, so it is sort of useless to use. You'll have to learn it eventually, so when you're building a new program, it might be easiest.

Moving on to what you are doing wrong, is that you have not actually fetched anything. MySQL will give you an object, and then you need to sort the rows.

So, what you need to do is pull `mysql_fetch_array`.

You can do so like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = $row["username"];
}
```

Comment: In order to use "username" as the index, don't you need to fetch as an associative array as in `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`?

Comment: Technically, no. `mysql_fetch_array` returns both numeric and associative keys at the same time. But, for the sake of clean code, I prefer `mysql_fetch_assoc`, which only returns the associative array

Comment: I also think mysql_fetch_row is very convenient when you're pulling only one result. Or mysql_fetch_object if you like the object style. The possibilities are endless!

Comment: Then I get this `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\adminedituser.php on line 18`

Comment: You probably have an error in your SQL syntax. Give us the feedback of what happens when you put or die(mysql_error()) after your query() function, before the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The form code shuld be changed to:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?= $id ?>' />
```

You forgot to "print" the $id value.

and the code of adminedituser.php:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id");
```

Get the "id" field from POST request of your form.

Comment: No dice, I can't get any value to display in the myForm, form.

Comment: It's not pulling the hidden value $id from the previous page